# Haivision SRT Protocol

Tags: c#

Есть данная open source библиотека https://github.com/Haivision/srt
Как с помощью нее реализовать передачу/прием данных по SRT протоколу?

Comment: Вы сами же дали ссылку, где [вот это вот всё](https://github.com/Haivision/srt/blob/master/docs/API.md) написано.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как интегрировать эту библиотеку в C# проект =(

Comment: [`[DllImport]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=netcore-3.1)